# Need to convert an array into object

Tags: javascript

Use Case :
I need the corresponding values from a CSV file to be displayed in the console based on the unique country which is selected.

I have Tried :-
1.)I tried converting the CSV file to an array using:
xmlData=xmlhttp.responseText

```
  var dataArr = xmlData.split("\n");
  var heading = dataArr[0].split(",");
  var data = dataArr.splice(1, dataArr.length - 1);
```

Below is the output of the array and 
I need to convert the below array to an JSON object so that if m giving switz as a key the corresponding values which is "5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown" should be displayed in the console.

```
[
"5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,switz
", "5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa
", "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,spider
", "5/19/2019 21:45:21,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san jose
", "5/19/2019 21:48:25,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san francisco
", "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,Los Angeles
", "5/19/2019 22:20:16,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san diego
", "5/19/2019 23:37:36,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,dubai
", "5/20/2019 0:23:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,new york
", "5/21/2019 4:04:53,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark
", "5/21/2019 4:08:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark
", "5/21/2019 4:09:52,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,germany
", "5/21/2019 4:11:34,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,delhi
", "5/21/2019 4:15:46,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa
", 
 "5/21/2019 4:53:59,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa
", "5/21/2019 4:55:08,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denamrk
", 
 "5/23/2019 4:21:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa barbara
", "5/23/2019 5:59:00,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa monica"]
```

Please help me to find an solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const response = [ "5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,switz ", "5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa ", "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,spider ", "5/19/2019 21:45:21,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san jose ", "5/19/2019 21:48:25,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san francisco ", "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,Los Angeles ", "5/19/2019 22:20:16,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san diego ", "5/19/2019 23:37:36,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,dubai ", "5/20/2019 0:23:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,new york ", "5/21/2019 4:04:53,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark ", "5/21/2019 4:08:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark ", "5/21/2019 4:09:52,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,germany ", "5/21/2019 4:11:34,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,delhi ", "5/21/2019 4:15:46,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa ", "5/21/2019 4:53:59,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa ", "5/21/2019 4:55:08,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denamrk ", "5/23/2019 4:21:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa barbara ", "5/23/2019 5:59:00,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa monica"];


let obj = {};
for(let r of response) {
  let arry = r.split(',');
  let key = arry.pop().trim()
  obj[key] = arry.join(',');
}

console.log(obj.switz)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
const array = [
  "5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,switz", 
  "5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa",
  "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,spider",
  "5/19/2019 21:45:21,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san jose",
  "5/19/2019 21:48:25,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san francisco",
  "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,Los Angeles",
];

let result = {};
for ( let element of array ) {
  let key = element.split( "," )[ 3 ];
  let split = element.split( "," );
  split.splice( -1, 1);

  element = split.join();
  
  result[ key ] = element;
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( result ) );
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response.I have used the same and got the exact result like :Los Angeles
": "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself �,mousedown"

Comment: Also please let me know how to input  the country in a web page(like prompting the user to enter country in a web page and based on that country the corresponding values should be automatically given as a alert to the user)

Comment: See: [window prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

Comment: Thankyou will try it using window.prompt..Using the above method when m trying to call result['africa'] like below:function resultCheck(){
  console.log(result["africa"]);
} it says undefined.Not sure why the object is not picked

Comment: Perhaps you have some kind of typo, or the object `result` is not within your current scope. The way you're calling it is perfectly fine syntax though.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that i understand you right, but if you want to convert this array to object which country as key and rest as value, then i write a bit of code for you :3
Also i apply JSON.stringify, if you need not javascript but json object.

```
let result = {}
const arr = ["5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,switz",
    "5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa",
    "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,spider",
    "5/19/2019 21:45:21,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san jose",
    "5/19/2019 21:48:25,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san francisco",
    "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,Los Angeles",
    "5/19/2019 22:20:16,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san diego",
    "5/19/2019 23:37:36,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,dubai",
    "5/20/2019 0:23:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,new york",
    "5/21/2019 4:04:53,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark",
    "5/21/2019 4:08:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark",
    "5/21/2019 4:09:52,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,germany",
    "5/21/2019 4:11:34,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,delhi",
    "5/21/2019 4:15:46,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa",
    "5/21/2019 4:53:59,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa",
    "5/21/2019 4:55:08,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denamrk",
    "5/23/2019 4:21:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa barbara",
    "5/23/2019 5:59:00,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa monica"]


for (let item of arr) {
    let temp = item.split(',');
    let key = temp.splice(3, 1);
    result[key] = temp.join(',');
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Output:

```
/*{
    "switz": "5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown",
    "africa": "5/21/2019 4:53:59,Try it Yourself �,mousedown",
    "spider": "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown"
    {...more items}
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [ // This's the data Array you should edit it with your above code !

  "Adnane",
  "Aref"
  
];

let jsonObj=JSON.stringify(data);

document.body.innerHTML=jsonObj; //Prints the first index of the JSON Object on the html body
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let arr = ["5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,switz", "5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa", "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,spider", "5/19/2019 21:45:21,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san jose", "5/19/2019 21:48:25,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san francisco", "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,Los Angeles", "5/19/2019 22:20:16,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san diego", "5/19/2019 23:37:36,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,dubai", "5/20/2019 0:23:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,new york", "5/21/2019 4:04:53,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark", "5/21/2019 4:08:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark", "5/21/2019 4:09:52,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,germany", "5/21/2019 4:11:34,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,delhi", "5/21/2019 4:15:46,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa", "5/21/2019 4:53:59,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa", "5/21/2019 4:55:08,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denamrk", "5/23/2019 4:21:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa barbara", "5/23/2019 5:59:00,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa monica"];

function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}
toObject(arr);
```

output

```
{
0: "5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,switz"
1: "5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,africa"
2: "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,spider"
3: "5/19/2019 21:45:21,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,san jose"
4: "5/19/2019 21:48:25,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,san francisco"
5: "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,Los Angeles"
6: "5/19/2019 22:20:16,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,san diego"
7: "5/19/2019 23:37:36,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,dubai"
8: "5/20/2019 0:23:51,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,new york"
9: "5/21/2019 4:04:53,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,denmark"
10: "5/21/2019 4:08:13,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,denmark"
11: "5/21/2019 4:09:52,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,germany"
12: "5/21/2019 4:11:34,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,delhi"
13: "5/21/2019 4:15:46,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,africa"
14: "5/21/2019 4:53:59,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,africa"
15: "5/21/2019 4:55:08,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,denamrk"
16: "5/23/2019 4:21:51,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,santa barbara"
17: "5/23/2019 5:59:00,Try it Yourself ï¿½,mousedown,santa monica"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const response = [ "5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,switz ", "5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa ", "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,spider ", "5/19/2019 21:45:21,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san jose ", "5/19/2019 21:48:25,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san francisco ", "5/19/2019 21:53:27,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,Los Angeles ", "5/19/2019 22:20:16,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,san diego ", "5/19/2019 23:37:36,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,dubai ", "5/20/2019 0:23:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,new york ", "5/21/2019 4:04:53,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark ", "5/21/2019 4:08:13,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denmark ", "5/21/2019 4:09:52,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,germany ", "5/21/2019 4:11:34,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,delhi ", "5/21/2019 4:15:46,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa ", "5/21/2019 4:53:59,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,africa ", "5/21/2019 4:55:08,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,denamrk ", "5/23/2019 4:21:51,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa barbara ", "5/23/2019 5:59:00,Try it Yourself �,mousedown,santa monica"];

const result = response.reduce((a, ele) => {
    a[ele.split(',').slice(-1)] = ele.split(',').slice(0, -1).join(',')
    return a
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let y = JSON.parse('["5/19/2019 20:49:57,Try it Yourself ,mousedown,switz","5/19/2019 21:38:49,Try it Yourself ,mousedown,africa", "5/19/2019 21:42:13,Try it Yourself ,mousedown,spider"]');
let mapArr = y.reduce((acc, obj) => { 
  var valuesArr = obj.split(",");
  let key = valuesArr.pop();
  acc[key] = valuesArr.join(',');
  return acc;
}, new Map());

console.log(mapArr["switz"])
```